# C program of accessing device file don't work

Tags: c, linux

I have seen [device file can be accessed directly in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520459/linux-hard-disk-direct-access-without-any-fs-from-c-program") and I want to have a try. I have a free disk partition without any file system. My test code is below.
I expect to get output `read data: 199` when I run the program at the second time. But actually, I get output `read data: 0` twice. No errors emerge during the program. I have no idea where is wrong.
Thanks for your time.

Test Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(){
    int num = 0;
    int fd = open("/dev/sda6", O_RDWR);

    if(fd == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "open device failed, errno : %s(%d) \n", 
            strerror(errno), errno);
        return 1;
    }

    ssize_t ret = read(fd, &num, sizeof(int));
    if(ret != sizeof(int)){
        fprintf(stderr, "read fails, errno : %s(%d) \n", 
            strerror(errno), errno);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("read data: %d\n", num);

    num = 199;
    ret = write(fd, &num, sizeof(int));
    if(ret != sizeof(int)){
        fprintf(stderr, "write fails, errno : %s(%d) \n", 
            strerror(errno), errno);
        return 1;
    }
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `read` and `write` start reading/writing at the implicit file offset stored in the descriptor, and increment it by the number of bytes read/written. Therefore, you would now read bytes 0 .. 3, and then write bytes 4 .. 7.

*Instead of `read` and `write` and messing with `lseek` et al*, use the POSIX standard [`pread` and `pwrite`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pwrite.2.html) that do not use the implicit file offset in the descriptor but take explicit file offsets from the beginning of a file in the call.

```
#include <unistd.h>
ssize_t pread(int fd, void *buf, size_t count, off_t offset);
ssize_t pwrite(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count, off_t offset);
```

...

```
ssize_t ret = pread(fd, &num, sizeof(int), 0);
ssize_t ret = pwrite(fd, &num, sizeof(int), 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not `seek` in your program, so what it does:
Read the first 4 bytes of the device, then write the second 4 bytes.

Try

```
lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);
```

before write if you want to write at the beginning of fole.